# How to a query to count values in a hierarchy tree

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

First off all, english is not my first language. So, sorry if a make any mistakes.

I did a query in MySQL to find the nodes in a hierarchytree table and found something like this (Table1) like this:

Hierarchy1id | Hierarchy 2id| Hierarchy3id| Hierarchy4id| Hierarchy5id 
 1      2                    
 1      2            3      4                    
 1      2            3      4              5

I have another table (Table 2) that is connected to Table 1 like this:

Parameters id | Hierarchy id 
 1      1      
 2      2      
 3      2      
 4      3      
 5      4

I want to count how many parameters are in all of hierarchies from table 1. How can i do that?

My sql to find table 1 is like this:

SELECT *
FROM table AS t1
   LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
   LEFT JOIN table AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
   LEFT JOIN table AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.id
   LEFT JOIN table AS t5 ON t5.parent_id = t4.id
WHERE t.1 = 1

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree